# this.props.children.map is not a function on arrayOf PropTypes - react-responsive-accordion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a problem with [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-accordion) react module for making nested accordions - long story short, because the original module is outdated, I'm using [this](https://github.com/lfurzewaddock/react-responsive-accordion) updated version, but it's still not working. I get this error:

```
TypeError: this.props.children.map is not a function
Accordion_render [as render]
src/components/react-responsive-accordion/src/Accordion.js:60
  57 | 
  58 | render: function() {
  59 | 
> 60 |   var nodes = this.props.children.map((node, index) => {
     | ^  61 | 
  62 |     var triggerWhenOpen = (node.props['data-trigger-when-open']) ? node.props['data-trigger-when-open'] : node.props['data-trigger'];
  63 |     var triggerDisabled = (node.props['data-trigger-disabled']) || false;
```

As far as I can tell, for some reason the validation of the prop types where it sets children to an array is not working:

```
  propTypes: {
    transitionTime: PropTypes.number,
    easing: PropTypes.string,
    startPosition: PropTypes.number,
    classParentString: PropTypes.string,
    onTriggerClick: PropTypes.func,
    closeable: PropTypes.bool,
    children: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape( // <----- HERE
      {
        props: PropTypes.shape({
          'data-trigger': PropTypes.oneOfType([
            PropTypes.string,
            PropTypes.element
          ]).isRequired,
          'data-triggerWhenOpen': PropTypes.oneOfType([
            PropTypes.string,
            PropTypes.element
          ]),        
          'data-triggerDisabled': PropTypes.bool,
        })
      }
    ))
  },
```

Does anyone have any advice? I've found some questions with similar problems but all were resolved by adding the arrayOf PropType. Thanks.

Comment: did u wrap any node with <Accordion> <somecomponent /></Accordion>

Comment: Hi, check in the debugger what kind of object you receive in this.props.children. this will tell you why there's no map function in it

Comment: In React the `children` prop is kind of special. I don't think that even specifying the `children` prop to be an array allows you to simply map it. You could revert your react version back to v15. In React v16+ you use `React.Children.map(children, mapFn)` [React.Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren).

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks, that helped me figure out the issue as noted in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - had to change

```
    var nodes = this.props.children.map((node, index) => {
```

To:

```
    var nodes = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (node, index) => {
```

Comment: That being said I encountered several other problems with the library, and decided to just use react-collapsible instead... :(